How to get $c$ is real from $cz\frac{\partial }{\partial z}$ is gradient vector field?
In picture below, I want to show $b=0$. So I calculate
$$
\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial u \partial v} =au g_v - bg  - bv g_v  \\
\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial v \partial u} = bvg_u + ag + aug_u
$$
Then, let $u=v=0$ and consider $\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial u \partial v}= \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial v \partial u}$, only $a+b=0$ I can get. I want know how to show $b=0$ ?




The formula for $\partial f/\partial v$ is wrong. It should be $bu+av$.

You're so sharp. Did you read this paper too?

Nope. I've never seen it. But it looks like you need to pay careful attention to little details :)
